# RAID 10 -- how do you know a drive is going or is bad?

Tags: linux, raid, hard-drive, hardware, hardware-raid

I have some servers with a datacenter all the servers have RAID 10 setup. How do I know when one of the drives is going bad or is bad and needs to be replaced?

EDIT: These servers are unmnaaged and hosted by providers so I don't actually have access to a lot of stuff.

EDIT: found out it was this one:
http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/support/raid/sas_raid/sas-3405/

So I need to install this?
http://www.adaptec.com/en-us/speed/raid/storage_manager/asm_linux_x64_v6_50_18579_tgz.htm

When installing(new to working with raid) will I have to end a menu and configure stuff or is it like a background service?

Comment: Depends on your raid controller.  Some expose the individual drives as `sgX` devices for SMART. Some you have to use their own tools for monitoring drive/array health.

Comment: @DerfK That's a very good point. Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

You see if the hard drives provide [S.M.A.R.T. data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.), poll it, monitor it, and send alerts based off of it. For example, [Nagios can do this](http://www.nagios.com/solutions/smart-monitoring), as can many, many other monitoring solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Without information about the specific host hardware, RAID controllers and drive types, we can't help much.

Perhaps the output of `cat /proc/scsi/scsi` or `lspci` may help a bit.